# pandas and resample compared to the len of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that stretches over the same period

```
"2016-05-13" to "2016-05-19"
```

`dfone` and `dftwo`

`dfone` length is `29542`
`dftwo` length is `11637`

I'd like to makeout the corrcoef, but I need the length of the two to be equal for that. Is there some way like

`dfone.resample(len(dftwo)).mean()`

edit:

The dates look like this:

```
2016-06-10 20:15:00+02:00    
2016-06-10 20:16:00+02:00   
2016-06-10 20:17:00+02:00   
2016-06-10 20:18:00+02:00  
2016-06-10 20:19:00+02:00
```

There's duplicates among the dates of the two dataframes. But they may not begin og end at the same exact time.

Comment: There is datetimeindex with `dates` only or with `time` too? Is possible resample both dataframe to equal length, but different as `dfone` and `dftwo` ?

Comment: Are duplicity in `date` values?

Comment: @jezrael I updated my question with answers

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `minutes` (because no seconds in sample) and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print (dfone)
                     col
2016-06-10 18:16:00    1
2016-06-10 18:16:00    3
2016-06-10 18:17:00    4
2016-06-10 18:17:00    1
2016-06-10 18:17:00    4
2016-06-10 18:18:00    1
2016-06-10 18:19:00    8

print (dftwo)
                     col1
2016-06-10 18:16:00     1
2016-06-10 18:16:00     3
2016-06-10 18:17:00     4
2016-06-10 18:18:00     1
2016-06-10 18:19:00     8

print (dfone.resample('1Min').mean())
                     col
2016-06-10 18:16:00    2
2016-06-10 18:17:00    3
2016-06-10 18:18:00    1
2016-06-10 18:19:00    8

print (dftwo.join(dfone.resample('1Min').mean()))
                     col1  col
2016-06-10 18:16:00     1    2
2016-06-10 18:16:00     3    2
2016-06-10 18:17:00     4    3
2016-06-10 18:18:00     1    1
2016-06-10 18:19:00     8    8
```